# MSBuild Error VS2015 Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

After an update of VS2015. When I build my cross platform app I get this build error without error No. "Xamarin.Forms require msbuild. xbuild is no longer supported." Anyone have an idea of the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve the issue by updating my xamarin.forms. I noticed the build targets pointed to a missing folder. Updating it adjusted the targets.

Answer (score 0):

I spent 8 hours trying to debug this today.  The **only** solution seems to be updating to VS 2017.